# Rails: cache_classes breaks one subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This seems to me like a bug. With this options in `development.rb`:

```
...
config.cache_classes => false
...
```

Just one subclass seems to disappear. If I comment out that subclass everything works as it should. Any help'd be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requiring the parent class in the class that needed it solved the issue.